# Elegant solution to take generated values on demand

Tags: javascript, sequence, system.reactive, lazy-evaluation, rxjs

I was wondering what would be the most elegant way to write an Observable sequence that produces an arbitrary number of  new computed results every time. I came up with the following:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {
  o.onNext(Math.random());
  o.onCompleted();
}).repeat(2000);
```

That would create 2000 new random values upon subscription. That solves it, but it is not elegant. I'd prefer a solution based on `take` rather than on repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use Rx.Observable.genereate. About it you can read here http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/generate.html or here https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md#rxobservablegenerateinitialstate-condition-iterate-resultselector-scheduler

Comment: That's exactly what `generate` is for.